# Error from mongo aggregate pipeline with $merge

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have a simple collection *alert* with _id and observables array

e.g.

```
{
  _id: '60d496b2d08d5f0630dea368',
  observables: ['10d496b2d08d5f0630dea368', '20d496b2d08d5f0630dea368'],
}
```

I created query to create new collection without array in format like:

```
{
  _id: <default id>,
  alertId: '60d496b2d08d5f0630dea368',
  observableId: '10d496b2d08d5f0630dea368',
{
  _id: <default id>,
  alertId: '60d496b2d08d5f0630dea368',
  observableId: '20d496b2d08d5f0630dea368',
}
```

Also, to prevent from duplication, unique index was created

```
collection.createIndex({ observableId: 1, alertId: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

And here is my query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$observables"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      observableId: "$observables",
      alertId: "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      into: {
        db: "some-db",
        coll: "some-coll"
      },
      on: [
        "observableId",
        "alertId"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

And as result got an error ***MongoError: Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique**

But the index was created, so any idea how to fix this error?

Link to [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/resvFVIcVgB)

Comment: Remove the `on` part of the $merge.

Comment: Are you sure that the unique index was on the correct db and collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in **collation**.

Index collation and query (in my case `db.collection.aggregate`) should have the same collation

Answer (score 1):

You can but do not **need** to create that index, what you need is to generate a unique `_id` value.

Since you are merging into an existing collection and not outputting into a new one, I suggest you create an _id field that is build from the concatenation of the `_id` and `observables` fields

e.g. using `$toString` and `$concat`:

```
"_id": {$concat: [{$toString: "$_id"}, "-", {$toString: "$observables"}]}
```

This way you have a repeatable process, where running twice will result in the same `_id` values.

You can merge into existing collection using:

```
{ $merge: { into: ..., on: "_id", whenMatched: "keepExisting", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
```

Full example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$observables"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: {$concat: [
        {$toString: "$_id"},
        "-",
        {$toString: "$observables"}
      ]},
      observableId: "$observables",
      alertId: "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      into: {db: "some-db", coll: "some-coll"},
      on: "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

Regarding the way you implemented it, my guess is the index is on the wrong database or collection i.e. not on the output collection.

Comment: I read "If the _id field is missing from a results document, MongoDB adds it automatically" from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#std-label-merge-on  as you don't need to generate the  `_id`.  Removing it should be enough for mongo to generate new ObjectId. Am I wrong?

Comment: It adds it automatically, however, the extra unique index slows things down, you can use the _id instead.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. Makes sense.